# public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php on line 23

Tags: php

Error_log

[02-Sep-2021 12:55:49 Europe/Istanbul] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /home/va*******t/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php on line 23
[02-Sep-2021 12:55:54 Europe/Istanbul] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /home/va*******t//public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php on line 23
[02-Sep-2021 12:55:54 Europe/Istanbul] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /home/va*******t//public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php on line 23

```
 [02-Sep-2021 12:55:55 Europe/Istanbul] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /home/va*******t//public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php on line 23
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

use Symfony\Polyfill\Php80 as p;

if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 80000) {
    return;
}

if (!defined('FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOL') && defined('FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN')) {
    define('FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOL', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
}

if (!function_exists('fdiv')) {
    function fdiv(float $num1, float $num2): float { return p\Php80::fdiv($num1, $num2); }
}
if (!function_exists('preg_last_error_msg')) {
    function preg_last_error_msg(): string { return p\Php80::preg_last_error_msg(); }
}
if (!function_exists('str_contains')) {
    function str_contains(string $haystack, string $needle): bool { return p\Php80::str_contains($haystack, $needle); }
}
if (!function_exists('str_starts_with')) {
    function str_starts_with(string $haystack, string $needle): bool { return p\Php80::str_starts_with($haystack, $needle); }
}
if (!function_exists('str_ends_with')) {
    function str_ends_with(string $haystack, string $needle): bool { return p\Php80::str_ends_with($haystack, $needle); }
}
if (!function_exists('get_debug_type')) {
    function get_debug_type($value): string { return p\Php80::get_debug_type($value); }
}
if (!function_exists('get_resource_id')) {
    function get_resource_id($res): int { return p\Php80::get_resource_id($res); }
}
```

Comment: And what's your PHP version?

Comment: PHP 7.4 (ea-php74)

Comment: This already answers your question.

Comment: Does php version need to be 8?

Comment: This is specifically designed to work on PHP 7.4. Are you 100% you are using 7.4?

Comment: yes %100 7.4 php

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using the latest version of  `"vlucas/phpdotenv"` package while on php5.6. I had to downgrade  `"vlucas/phpdotenv"` to version `^2.4` or later.

You might want to check that all your packages are compatible with your current php version in your `composer.json`